# Fetching all Software Center reviews?

Tags: 11.04, software-center

When you select an item in the **Software Center** its user reviews are fetched, and saved. Is there a way to fetch the reviews for all items in the Software Center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A newly released update to the Software Center has solved this issue. All reviews are fetched by default now.